# UIPanGestureRecognizer でパンを開始した座標を取得するには？

Tags: objective-c

UIPanGestureRecognizer でジェスチャーを取得して動作するアプリを作成中です。
パンを開始する際にタッチした座標によって動作を切り替えたいと思っているのですが、
パンのアクションメソッドで translationInView: と同様に指定したビュー内でタッチした座標を取得する方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 自己レスです。UIPanActionRecognaizerは translationInView だけではなく、 locationInView 使えたんですね。解決しました…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer`（`UIPanGestureRecognizer`のスーパークラス）のメソッド`- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view`で取得できます。
同じく`UIGestureRecognizer`のプロパティ`state`で、ジェスチャー開始`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`、ジェスチャー継続中`UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`、ジェスチャー終了`UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`を識別できるので、`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`で`locationInView:`を使い、タッチした座標を取得します。

*`UIPanGestureRecognizer`インスタンスで指定したアクションメソッド*

```
- (void)panGesture: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    CGPoint startPoint;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        startPoint = [gesture locationInView: theView];
    }
}
```